# Convert timezone name to GMT timezone offset, in Perl?

Tags: perl, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a timzeone name as input, for example '`Europe/Istanbul`' as a string. 
How can I get the current offset from GMT (based on current time), i.e. `+2` as output ? 
PS, I am using [DateTime::TimeZone](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-TimeZone/lib/DateTime/TimeZone.pm) if this may help

Comment: you can't; you can only get the offset from GMT *at a particular time*

Comment: How come ! will the offset from GMT change from moment to moment (based on passed time parameter) ?!

Comment: In my time zone, the offset is either -4 or -5 depending on the time of year.

Comment: So lets assume I want to get it based on current moment, i.e. now. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 8):

You can get the current offset using DateTime::TimeZone's [`offset_for_datetime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-TimeZone/lib/DateTime/TimeZone.pm#$tz-%3Eoffset_for_datetime(_$dt_)) method or DateTime's [`offset`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm#$dt-%3Eoffset%28%29) method. A DateTime object is required because the offset can vary based on the date-time (primarily because of Daylight Saving Time).

```
my $tz_name = 'Europe/Istanbul';

my $dt = DateTime->now( time_zone => $tz_name );
for (1..2) {
    my $offset = $dt->offset;
    printf("Offset for %s in %s is %+g\n", $dt->iso8601, $tz_name, $offset / 60 / 60);
    $dt->add( months => 6 );
}
```

Output:

```
Offset for 2015-02-18T18:20:30 in Europe/Istanbul is +2
Offset for 2015-08-18T18:20:30 in Europe/Istanbul is +3
```

Comment: or just `my $offset=DateTime->now(time_zone=>$tzName)->offset`

Comment: The offset can vary based on the date-time (primarily because of Daylight Saving Time). Update answer to make that clear

Comment: I think that assuming it is changed every 6 month is not correct. Check for example how the daylight changes in a country like egypt: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/egypt/cairo

Answer (score 1):

The offset can be obtained using the following:

```
$dt->offset
```

The offset of a date-time can vary based on the data-time (primarily due to Daylight Saving Time). As such, an offset is only useful when used in conjunction with the specific date-time for which it was obtained. That means there are very few legitimate uses of an offset other than for formatting a date-time for communication. For this purpose, you might find the `%z` `strftime` variable more useful.

```
$ perl -MDateTime -E'
   say DateTime->now( time_zone => "local" )->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
'
2015-02-18T10:52:40-0800
```